# Uncaught Exception in Symfony based application when uploaded to remote server

Tags: php, symfony, caching, kernel, localhost

Im curently using the Symfony Kernel and Symfony console on a custom framework I have developed on my local machine everything runs smoothly but when I uploaded the application. I get the error below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message 'The Response content must be a string or object implementing
>   __toString(), "boolean" given.'

From my googles, it seems to be generated from the Symfony cache and I should clear it for the error to disappear but as Im only using the kernel and the console I am not sure when to get the folder and delete or access the app/console and run it from the CLI.

Comment: The folder is on app/cache on symfony 2.* and var/cache on symfony >= 3.

Comment: @MathieuDormeval Can you be a bit more specific Im using Symfony with Composer and the folders are quite many so Im not sure where app/cache or var/cache maybe located.

Comment: @StanleyNgumo See http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html

Comment: Behind the root of your project named symfony (like /var/www/symfony/).